# Disable expanded notifications in Android v6

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications

Is it possible to disable expanded notifications in Android v6? I can't even "collapse" them with two fingers. They start to collapse but go back to "expanded" when let go. Looking to prohibit expansion by default. Don't mind it being expandable manually but not by default without touching it.